# Xamarin workingwithwebview Example

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, emulation

I am trying to execute the workingwithwebview example which is unmodified from the downloaded code and running in the 5" Kitkat 4.4 XXHDPI emulator that came installed on VS2015 Community. It blows with error XA5213 java.lang.outofmemory error. I have found things that suggest editing the emulator config file, but that doesn't seem to help. The message returned indicates that the javamaximumheapsize should be increased, but I can't find this setting. Any help to make this run?

Comment: Heap Size should be a setting in the Advanced properties of the Android Build tab in your Droid project options

Comment: Well that was easy. I guess that would be why I couldn't find that simple answer. Thanks.